# how to code simple motion tracking?

Tags: motion-detection

I am making a sentry turret with servos and a paintball gun and need to implement real time motion tracing to make the gun shoot anything that moves. how can I code this(any good algorithms, books, tutorials)?  I want to make it myself and not use premade solutions.

Comment: for all the people thinking i am too lazy to google, the point of asking something on stackoverflow is to get knowledge from people who may have already done somehting like this and may suggest something that a simple google search wont turn up, so unless you have something constructive to add please shut up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucas-Kanade with Kalman filtering is the bread and butter motion tracking algorithm.  However, it's a bit outdated.

Comment: A bit late to ask, but what's a better way to do this? I'm working on something similar, but I'm examining a book from a webcam and detecting page turns (I need the direction). Thanks for the answer too!

Comment: Hey, open source for Lucas-Kanade tracking for the iPhone here - http://www.success-ware.com/150842/Lucas-Kanade-Detection-for-the-iPhone

Answer (score 1):

We (Success Labs) just published a Lucas-Kanade app for the iPhone. You can read about it here - http://www.success-ware.com/150842/Lucas-Kanade-Detection-for-the-iPhone

There's a link to the AppStore, and source code as well.

HTH,
Oded.