# How can I detect the movement of an rectangle in an image-stream efficiently?

Tags: motion, motion-detection

I'd like to find an algorithm that can detect the movement (and movement-vector) of a rectangular area -- like scrolling a window would produce -- in an image-stream. Any ideas? :)

Comment: did you try to read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124740/how-to-code-simple-motion-tracking

Comment: yes, however, the discussion is 1.not helpful 2. refers to general motion detection. I know that a whole rectangle moves, so this should in principle be faster.

Answer (score 0):

*Optical Flow*'s idea should work, but it depends on the type of features you have in the window (images, text), and whether they're unique enough to be matched reliably in subsequence frames.

*RANSAC* is a method of given two images, it would compute the homography affine transformation from one image to the other, given that the features matched between them are mostly matched correctly